# Why is my recursive function not working?

Tags: php, recursion

```
$startDate = 20130201;
$date      = 20130505;
$aDates    = $this->getDates($startDate, $date);

public function getDates($startDate, $date) {
    $tmpStartDate = date("Ymd", strtotime($startDate.'+1 Day'));
    $tmpEndDate   = date("Ymd", strtotime($tmpStartDate.'+1 Month'));

    if($date >= $tmpStartDate && $date <= $tmpEndDate) {
        //return array('startDate' => $tmpStartDate, 'endDate' => $tmpEndDate);
    } else {
        $this->getDates($tmpEndDate, $date);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is it supposed to do? what does it do instead? does it throw any errors? or exceptions?

Comment: The uncommented bit should be uncommented and still doesn't work

Comment: Because it does not know what it should do. Ok, seriously: What are you trying to achieve and what is the (bogus) result produced by your function?

Comment: I'm trying to add a day to start and a month to end each time and detect if $date lies between the two, if it does, return the $tmpStartDate and $tmpEndDate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the }else{ is called, nothing gets returned from the recursive call.

Try uncommenting your commented line and adding "return" to the beginning of that else clause:

```
return $this->getDates($tmpEndDate, $date);
```

Comment: Damn that appears to have worked. Forgot you need to return to itself.

Comment: Good answer.  @user275074: Stack Overflow relies on having its questions marked with the correct answer.  You can do so by clicking the tick icon to the left of the answer under the up/down voting buttons.  PS Welcome to Stack Overflow!